# How should I resolve a question that we deduced isn't a problem and thus doesn't need solving?

Tags: support, self-answer

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10710511/680578) and while the code I posted was being vetted in the comments, we realized that my code did, in fact, work and that something else (out of my control) was the cause.

For the sake of the question's clarity 2 years from now, is it better to add an answer stating that, and accept that answer, or should I just close the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the question has no answers, you could just delete it.

However, if you think that the problem may trip others up, post an answer with the solution and accept that.

Answer (score 2):

It has no answers, it is quite unlikely to ever be helpful to somebody else, just delete it.